# How do I change the color of a scatterpoint in the legend?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, pandas

I'm creating a scatterplot of data from a pandas dataframe, and want to emphasize one particular point in my scatterplot.

right now, my code is:

```
plt.scatter(x_cors, y_cors, s=50, color=colors)
plt.legend(['name'], scatterpoints=1, loc="lower left", fontsize=10)
plt.show()
```

In my colors array, every element is yellow except for one point which is green.  In my legend I want to explain what the green point is, but the point always shows up as yellow. is there any way to manually change this to be green?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just plot that single point with a different color:

```
plt.scatter([x], [y], color='g') # Replace x and y to the coordinate you want
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to define the colors element as `'g'` and `'y'` rather than `green` or `yellow` or just `g` or `y`.

Instead, the easiest way is to omit the green data  point from your array, and give that a new array, such as `x_cors_green, y_cors_green = [???,???]`. Then you can simply add in another scatter:

```
plt.scatter(x_cors, y_cors, s=50, color='y')
plt.scatter(x_cors_green, y_cors_green, s=50, color='g')
plt.legend(['name'], scatterpoints=1, loc="lower left", fontsize=10)
plt.show()
```